# Get access_token in Facebook Connect

Tags: java, facebook, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am a little new to Java Playframework and testing out the Facebook authentication.

```
public static Result fbLogin(){
    String token_code_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/&response_type=token";
    return redirect(token_code_url);
}


public static Result index() {

Result loginResult = fbLogin();
return loginResult;

}
```

This opens Facebook, and i give access to my app.

it returns with `http://localhost:9000/#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

How do i get the ACCESS_TOKEN ?

Do I need to configure the routes ? I seem to get a `This webpage has a redirect loop` on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use the client-side authentication: The part of the URL after "#" is not sent to the server.

I suggest you use one of the available modules to do the Facebook login, for example, SecureSocial: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial or Play! Authenticate: http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/

Comment: Are those compatible with the play 2.0 ?

Comment: Graph API (Wasn't part of the question): You should be able to access the Graph API also through these products. Play2: Yes, they are both modules for Play 2.0